# Replacement lamp shade

Tags: lamp

I would like to replace the lamp shade for the lower light.

I could fabricate something.

The knurled ring can be tightened down.

Anyone have any ideas on what material to use for the shade.

[image]

Comment: The knurled ring should unscrew entirely.  So you can use or make any shade with the right size mounting hole.

Comment: If wanting to make your own, there should be designs plenty out there.  The only problem I can see is that looks like a flex shaft holding the light.  The weight of the shade might be harder to keep low enough doing it DIY to keep that shaft from moving/dropping down.

Comment: @fixit7 `any ideas?` is not a question about a specific problem ... the rest of the post does not describe a problem either ... it only describes the goal of a project ... please describe the problem that is preventing you from completing your project ... the way it is now, it seeks a solution to an unspecified problem

Comment: Not having a shade for the bulb is a problem. It causes glare. @jsotola

Comment: the only limitation is that the shade material is not flammable ... visit a lighting store for ideas ... you could have one made by a glass artisan, or make one by drilling a hole in the bottom of a decorative flower pot ... you could rebuild an old lampshade with new materials ...  your question does not have a "correct" answer, so it is deemed to be opinion based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to get a [lampshade that clips onto the light bulb](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=clip%20on%20lamp%20shade&crid=1JV8KTDK3CRBM&sprefix=Clip%20on%20lamp%2Caps%2C141&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_2_12). This Amazon.com search gives examples, both of complete shades and holders that take standard shades.

Comment: Agree.  There are 1000s of replacements available in different designs and mounting choices.  Making one seems like too much work.